# Good way to manage the Documents/Inbox folder in an iOS app

Tags: ios

When a file is passed into an iOS application by the document interaction system, a copy of the file is stored in the application bundle's `Documents/Inbox` folder. After the application has processed the file, it obviously needs to remove the file from `Documents/Inbox`, otherwise the folder will continue to grow and waste storage on the device.

I am uncomfortable with this simple solution (A), however, because my app needs to interact with the user before it can finish processing and removing the file. If the user suspends the app during this interaction period, and the app then gets killed while it is in the background, the stale file will not be removed when the app starts up the next time. Of course I can improve my app to cover this scenario, but I suspect that there will always be another border case that will leave me with an "unclean" `Documents/Inbox` folder.

A preferrable solution (B) therefore would be to remove the `Documents/Inbox` folder at an appropriate time (e.g. when the app launches normally, i.e. not via document interaction). I am still uncomfortable with this because I would be accessing a filesystem path whose location is not officially documented anywhere. For instance, my app would break if in a future version of iOS the document interaction system no longer places files in `Document/Inbox`.

So my questions are:

1. Would you recommend solution A or B?
2. Do you use a different approach and can you maybe give an outline of how your app manages `Document/Inbox`?
3. Last but not least: Do you know a piece of official Apple documentation that covers the topic and that I have overlooked?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Since I have asked this question, I have implemented the following solution:

- I have redesigned my app so that it now immediately processes a file handed over to it via documentation interaction, without involving the user at all. Unless the app crashes, or is suspended and killed, in the middle of processing the file, this should always leave me with a clean `Documents/Inbox`.
- To cover the (rare) case of a crash or suspend/kill, my app removes the `Documents/Inbox` folder when it is launched normallly (i.e. without the purpose of document interaction). To achieve this the `Documents/Inbox` folder path is necessarily hardcoded.

Here are the thoughts that went into the solution:

- Redesigning the app

  - Initially it seemed like a good idea to offer the user a choice how she wanted a file to be processed - after all, offering a choice would make the app more flexible and provide the user with more freedom, right?
  - I then realized that I was trying to shift the responsibility for deciding how document interaction should be handled to the user. So I bit the bullet, made the hard decisions up-front, and then went happily on to implement a simple and straightforward document interaction system in my app.
  - As it turns out, no user interaction also means that the app is easier to use, so here's a win-win situation, both for me as a developer and for the users of my app.
- Removing `Documents/Inbox` folder during app launch

  - Removing the `Documents/Inbox` folder during app launch is just an afterthought, not an *essential* part of how my app handles document interaction
  - Therefore I am quite willing to take the risk that Apple might change the filesystem path of the inbox folder at some point in the future. The worst thing that can happen is that my app will start to accumulate a few files that are leftovers from crash or suspend/kill scenarios.

And finally, a few thoughts for further development:

- If it ever turns out that there *really* should be more than one way how the app can handle document interaction, I would add a user preference so that the user has to make a decision up-front, and the app does not need to stop its processing to ask the user for a choice.
- If it ever turns out that user interaction is absolutely unavoidable in the middle of the document interaction handling process, I would look at this approach: 1) Before the user is allowed to interact, move the file from `Documents/Inbox` to some sort of "staging" folder; 2) Let user interaction take place; 3) Process the file in the "staging" folder, in whatever way the user chose. The important thing here is that the "staging" folder is *in a known location and is completely managed by the app*. Should the user suspend and then kill the app in the middle of the user interaction step, an appropriate action can simply be taken when the app is launched for the next time.

---

**EDIT**

In iOS 7 it is no longer possible to remove `Documents/Inbox` once it has been created. The `NSFileManager` method `removeItemAtPath:error:` returns Cocoa error 513 which resolves to `NSFileWriteNoPermissionError` (cf. [this list of Foundation constants](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Miscellaneous/Foundation_Constants/Reference/reference.html)). The error does not seem to be related to POSIX permissions, however, it rather looks as if the system itself interferes with the attempt at deletion (possibly protection of the app bundle structure?).

Also noteworthy is that nowadays Apple explicitly names `Documents/Inbox` in the documentation of the `UIApplicationDelegate` method `application:openURL:sourceApplication:annotation:`. They also say that

> [...] Your app has permission to read and delete files in this directory but does not have permission to write to them. If you want to modify a file, you must move it to a different directory first.

There is more stuff about possible encryption of the files in [the docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/uikit/reference/UIApplicationDelegate_Protocol/), but you should read up on that yourself.

Comment: "...I bit the bullet, made the hard decisions up-front..." - good for you! Too often developers handle complexity by throwing up their hands and deferring decisions to the user, which can rapidly lead to a hard-to-understand and frustrating app experience. This solution is very close to what I would've responded with.

Answer (score 9):

This problem has become much more complicated with the introduction of the Files app, and the "Open in place" feature.

If you do **not** have "Supports opening documents in place" switched on, in your `info.plist`, then things are pretty much the same, and files opened from any other app still appear in the `Documents/Inbox` directory. But files opened from the Files app appear in another inbox, currently at `tmp/<bundle ID of app>-inbox`. It is still recommended to delete the file once you are done with it, but there is less need to occasionally clean the directory, because the `tmp` directory gets cleaned by iOS once in a while anyways.

If you **do** have "Supports opening documents in place" switched on, then things change drastically. Files opened from the Files app and some other apps are no longer copied into an inbox, but they are passed to you at their original location. That is typically some location inside the Files app itself, inside another app referenced from the Files app, or even some general iCloud location. If you expose the files in your Documents folder, then it could even be one of your own app's files.

Needless to say, if you get such a file, you **must not** delete it. But if the file comes in an inbox, which will still happen a lot as well, then you **must** delete it. In order to determine this, the options of the `application:openURL:options:` call contains an [`UIApplicationOpenURLOptionsOpenInPlaceKey`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationopenurloptionsopeninplacekey) key. If that has value (`NSNumber`) NO, then the file is in an inbox, and it should be deleted. It it has value YES, then it is opened in-place, and must not be deleted.

Note that for files that are opened in place, you also need to gain permission to use them first. You do that but surrounding the access to the file by `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource` and `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource` calls. See [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso) for details.

Answer (score 0):

I am just now facing this same problem.  Like you I don't have a good solution but in response to your questions I'm leaning towards option A over option B because I don't like the idea of potentially having an issue with future releases of the OS.  Since, in my case, there is no user interaction once I display the preview of the document, I can go ahead and delete it when when I receive the `–documentInteractionControllerDidEndPreview:` delegate callback.  This is theoretical in that I haven't coded this yet and won't get to it for a while as it is a low priority item.  If it doesn't work or there are other issues, I will report back here.  The Google search I entered in order to find documentation from Apple pointed to this StackOverflow post. I haven't seen any other useful information from Apple or anyone else on the subject.