# NSFileManager moveItem throws Error Code=513

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, nsfilemanager, ios13

I'm trying to move a file from a URL to another, however I get an error with code `513`. I understand that this is a `NSFileWriteNoPermissionError`. I don't see how this possible considering I created the folder in the first place.

```
//self.video!.folderURL.path = /var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/066BDB03-FD47-48D8-B6F8-932AFB174DF7/Documents/AV/769c504203024bae95b47d78d8fe9029
try? fileManager.createDirectory(atPath: self.video!.folderURL.path, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: nil)

// Update permission for AV folder
do {
     let parentDirectoryPath = self.video!.folderURL.deletingLastPathComponent().path
     let result = try fileManager.setAttributes([FileAttributeKey.posixPermissions: 0o777], ofItemAtPath: parentDirectoryPath)
        print(result)
     } catch {
        print("Error = \(error)")
     }

// sourceURL = file:///private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/50D8B8DB-19D3-4DD6-93DD-55F37CF87EA7/tmp/trim.6D37DFD2-5F27-4AB9-B478-5FED8AA6ABD7.MOV
// self.url = file:///var/mobile/Containers/Data/Application/066BDB03-FD47-48D8-B6F8-932AFB174DF7/Documents/AV/0b0b6803e891780850152eeab450a2ae.mov
do {
     try fileManager.moveItem(at: sourceURL, to: self.url)
   } catch {
     QLogTools.logError("Error moving video clip file \(error)")
   }
```

**Error**

Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=513 "“trim.90A10B33-B884-419F-BAD9-65583531C3C3.MOV” couldn’t be moved because you don’t have permission to access “AV”." UserInfo={NSSourceFilePathErrorKey=/private/var/mobile/Containers/Data/PluginKitPlugin/0849234B-837C-43ED-BEDD-DE4F79E7CE96/tmp/trim.90A10B33-B884-419F-BAD9-65583531C3C3.MOV, NSUserStringVariant=(
Move

I tried altering the permission of the folder I created in the first place to 0o777, but when I print out its attributes it returns 511 as its permissions.

**P.S**:This only happens on iOS 13.

Comment: How do you know you have the right to access the source URL?

Comment: @ElTomato I've updated the question with the error.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Did you get it solved?

Comment: As a temporary workaround, I use the `copy` method instead of `move` and it works.

Comment: I am having this issue and nothing helps . any other solution?

Answer (score 5):

I solved my issue, but it may be different to what you were experiencing: I still had issues when changing to `copyItem`. I'm adding my findings here as an answer in case anyone else stumbles upon this question as I did and it helps them out.

My app loads custom files that can be downloaded from my website. With iOS 13's download manager, these are copied to the Downloads folder first, and can then be opened by my app. Yet my app was having permission errors when attempting to access these files in the same way as iOS 12.

[This answer to a different question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57632194/555807) clued me in. I need to call `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` and `stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` as follows:

```
// source and destination are URLs
if source.startAccessingSecurityScopedResource() {
    try FileManager.default.moveItem(at: source, to: destination)
}
source.stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource()
```

The [Apple documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/foundation/nsurl/1417051-startaccessingsecurityscopedreso) doesn't really suggest that this is new with iOS 13 but I think just the different approach to file downloading means sandboxing considerations need to be made.

Comment: This solved it for me, although the stopAccessingSecurityScopedResource() call should be within the brackets.

Comment: Didn't work in my case. I tried calling  `startAccessingSecurityScopedResource()` on both the source and destination but it returned false in both instances. Changing it from `moveItem` to `copyItem` was my fix (moving a video from UIImagePickerController selection)